# Does a child created via clone inherits its parent's CPU affinity mask?

Tags: c++, linux, clone

I am using sched_setaffinity(2) to set the process CPU affinity and then I am cloning few child processes.

Does a child created via **clone** inherits its parent's CPU affinity mask?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`shed_setaffinity()`  *determines the set of CPUs on which the process is eligible to run.*

This [article](http://lwn.net/Articles/127936/) explains that *to start a new job that is to be contained within a cpuset, the steps are: (...) fork, exec or **clone** the job tasks from this founding father task.*

So the answer is yes